# How do I get Visual Studio 2013 to allow me to target .NET Framework 4.5.2?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, .net-framework-version

I've got a project that has some references that were giving me the following issue:

> The primary reference "reference" could not be resolved because it was
>   built against the ".NETFramework, Version=v4.5.2" framework. This is a
>   higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,
>   Version=v4.5.1".

So I thought I'll just install 4.5.2 and then target my project to that. So, I installed it, rebooted and checked it was there as per [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx). This proved it had been installed. However, when I re-opened my project in VS 2013 my available target framework only went up to 4.5.1.

So my question is, how can I get VS 2013 to now recognise that I have 4.5.2 installed?

Comment: did you installed the Developer Pack... this link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637 ???

Comment: .NET 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 are runtime revisions, they have very few useful additions to the framework.  Nor would you want to force your clients to upgrade if it isn't necessary.  Strive to only target 4.5, pass the word to whomever supplies you with libraries.

Comment: @HansPassant - ordinarily I would agree, however this is a requirement of using libraries for MS Dynamics CRM 2015. I'll pass the word to Microsoft ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the developer pack of the .NET Framework you wish to use then https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637:

1. In Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the project that you want to change, and then choose Properties.
2. In the left column of the properties window, choose the Application tab.
3. In the Target Framework list, choose the version that you want.
4. In the verification dialog box that appears, choose the Yes button.
   The project unloads. When it reloads, it targets the .NET Framework version that you just chose.

You should know that certain features might or might not be available in a later version and you might need to fix them when changing to a different version of the .NET framework

In my experience, I usually have a new version of the .NET Framework displayed in VS after a restart. I am using VS2013 at the moment

Comment: He said the list of target frameworks does not contain Version 4.5.2 of the framework.

Comment: @viertausend I suspect the OP did not install the pack correctly or installed the incorrect pack. Following Dave's instructions should cause 4.5.2 to show up.

Comment: I'm installing the Developer Pack now and seeing if this works. I'll let you know...

Comment: Great solution for loading one project on Windows 7 and Windows 10